# XMLHttpRequest sends local data twice

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using XMLHttpRequest's send method to upload the data that are saved in a local sqlite database, to my own website. On my website I'm running phpMyAdmin. The issue that I'm having is that the data gets transmitted to the server twice, even though the local sqlite database stores the data only once. I was wondering if anyone could help me to identify the issue. I also made sure to use XMLHttpRequest asynchronously, I still don't understand why is this happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
postData: function(count) {
    var surveyURL = "https://example.com/data/logging/answer.php";
    var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["ext.sqlite"]);
    var dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
    var query = dbConn.createStatement("SELECT * FROM responses");
    var i = 0;
    while (query.step()) {
      let data = {
        'rowid' : query.row.rowid,
        'timestamp' : query.row.timestamp,
        'uid' : query.row.uid,
        'warning' : query.row.warning,
        'ignored' : query.row.ignored,
        'domain' : query.row.domain,
        'qid' : query.row.qid,
        'response' : query.row.response
        };

        let xmlhttp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", surveyURL, true);
        xmlhttp.timeout = 5000;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                if (/^0: Survey \d+ added/.test(xmlhttp.responseText)) {
                    //data was added successfully, delete the row id from local database
                        let matches = xmlhttp.responseText.match(/^0: Survey \d+ added \((\d+)\)/);
                        let rowid = matches[1];
                    ext.Debug.dump("Deleting row " + rowid);
                    try {
                        //commented this line out, because at first I thought this was the issue but itsn't?!
                        //dbConn.executeSimpleSQL("DELETE FROM responses WHERE rowid=" + rowid);
                    } catch(e) {
                        ext.Debug.dump("Error deleting row: " + e);
                    }
                } else {
                    ext.Debug.dump("Remote error: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
            try {
            xmlhttp.send(ext.js.toString(data));
            } catch (e) {
            ext.Debug.dump("Error transmitting results: " + e);
            }
    query.reset();
  },

  testConnection: function() {
    //checks whether we can reach our server
    //only test the connection if we have stuff to upload
    //do this asynchronously
    var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["ext.sqlite"]);
        var dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
        var query=dbConn.createStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM responses");
        query.executeAsync({
            handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
                let count = aResultSet.getNextRow().getResultByIndex(0);
                ext.Debug.dump(count + " records to upload");
                if (count>0) {
                    var testURL = "https://example.com/data/connected.php";
                    var xmlhttp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", testURL, true);
                    xmlhttp.timeout = 5000;
                    var date = Date.now();
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                            if (xmlhttp.responseText == date) {
                                ext.js.postData(count);
                                ext.Debug.dump("connected!");
                            } else {
                                ext.Debug.dump("not connected");
                            }
                        } else {
                            ext.Debug.dump("not connected");
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.ontimeout=function() {
                        ext.Debug.dump("not connected! 3");
                    }

                    try {
                        xmlhttp.send("time=" + date);
                    } catch (e) {
                        ext.Debug.dump("Error connecting: " + e);
                    }
            }

            },

            handleError: function(aError) {
                ext.Debug.dump("Error: " + aError.message);
            },          

        });
        dbConn.asyncClose();    
  },
```